# how to find if a Tx hash is in pending state in ethereum mainnet after web3j fastTxMgr timeout

Tags: ether, web3j, rinkeby, web3js-v1.x

I am using QueuingTransactionReceiptProcessor() with callback accept(). DEFAULT_POLLING_ATTEMPTS_PER_TX_HASH is 10 and POLLING_FREQUENCY is 15000. That gives nearly 3 min wait for network to acknowledge. But I noticed that ethereum mainnet takes 8 to 10 minutes to give a response. At the end of timeout window (which leads to exception), i want to check if TxHash is still in pending state with the network and if so extend the timeout interval. Timeout does not really mean transaction has failed on the network. It could mean I need to wait for more time. it works fine on r

Comment: no issues on rinkeby as the transactions complete under 150 seconds

Comment: correction: I am using FastRawTransactionManager(). I don't think it makes a difference for the answer though

Answer (score 0):

I havn't used "QueuingTransactionReceiptProcessor()" yet, but maybe this could help you

```
EthGetTransactionReceipt transactionReceipt =
                    web3j.ethGetTransactionReceipt(txHash).send();
if (transactionReceipt.getResult() != null && !transactionReceipt.hasError()) {             
    String statusOfTx =  transactionReceipt.getTransactionReceipt().get().getStatus();
    ..check the status and do something..
}
```